# Using timepicker to set time

Tags: android, timepicker

**There are two edit text** ::

[image]

Onclick of edittext timepicker should pop up

### How to use the time picker to select the date & set the date in the two edit text

- I have googled abut timepicker
- But i dont know how to launch the timepicker on click of edittext and
  set time

**XML**::

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="3dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lunch_from_textview_id"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/image1"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lunch_button_id"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:text="From"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/from_lunch_edit_text_id"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lunch_to_textview_id"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lunch_button_id"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="To"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <requestFocus />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/to_lunch_edit_text_id"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:ems="10" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

**BuffetOfferings_MainFragmentActivity.java**

```
public class BuffetOfferings_MainFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    Button back_button;

    FragmentManager manager;
    FragmentTransaction transaction;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.buffet_offerings_fragment_main_reference);

        Buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu1 breakfast_fragment=new Buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu1();
        Buffet_offerings_lunch_menu1 lunch_fragment=new Buffet_offerings_lunch_menu1();
        Buffet_offerings_dinner_menu1 dinner_fragment=new Buffet_offerings_dinner_menu1();

        manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        transaction=manager.beginTransaction();

        transaction.add(R.id.BREAKFAST_LAYOUT_ID,breakfast_fragment, "breakfast_menu1_fragment");
        transaction.add(R.id.LUNCH_LAYOUT_ID,lunch_fragment, "lunch_menu1_fragment");
        transaction.add(R.id.DINNER_LAYOUT_ID,dinner_fragment, "dinner_menu1_fragment");

        transaction.commit();



        back_button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.TopNavigationBarRestaurantBuffetOfferingsBackButton);
        back_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();

            }
        });



    }



}
```

Comment: in which edittext do you want to set time..??

Comment: For both the edit text .... seperately :)

Comment: Okay...SO you have to call click event method for it....and just declared another static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID_MY = 1 variable..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on your EditText or Button....

```
mPickTimeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // show the time picker dialog
            DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
            newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
        }
    }); // this is on onCreate() method..

@Override
public void onTimePicked(Calendar time)
{
    // display the selected time in the TextView
    mPickedTimeText.setText(DateFormat.format("h:mm a", time));
}
```

After that create a class **TimePickerFragment** which is extends with **DialogFragment**

```
  public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener
{
  private TimePickedListener mListener;

  @Override
 public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    // use the current time as the default values for the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    // create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
  }

  @Override
   public void onAttach(Activity activity)
  {
    // when the fragment is initially shown (i.e. attached to the activity), cast the activity to the callback interface type
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try
    {
        mListener = (TimePickedListener) activity;
    }
    catch (ClassCastException e)
    {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement " + TimePickedListener.class.getName());
    }
  }

 @Override
 public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
 {
    // when the time is selected, send it to the activity via its callback interface method
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

    mListener.onTimePicked(c);
 }

  public static interface TimePickedListener
 {
    public void onTimePicked(Calendar time);
 }
}
```

Comment: @smriti3 but if you run your app it will be crashed because you have call fragment on oncreate..So how can your current view of time picker will be displayed??

Comment: oops ...yes u r right ! .... let me recreate whole thing in fragment class ..... yes i think that was the problem .... thanks for help ... ill mark answer as correct :)

Comment: @smriti3 Thanks for that...and yes if you have problem then chat with room...thx..

Comment: @PiyushGupta http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html. Should you not be using a `DialogFragment` here

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes...why not??

Comment: @PiyushGupta `public final boolean showDialog (int id, Bundle args)`

Added in API level 8
**This method was deprecated in API level 13.**
**Use the new DialogFragment class with FragmentManager instead; this is also available on older platforms through the Android compatibility package**.

Comment: @smriti3 pls check my previous comment

Answer (score 1):

We can do it smriti3 ,Please try my below sample code and let me know if you found any issues,

```
 <EditText 
    android:id="@+id/add_TimePicker"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:textColor="#38251f"                   
    android:focusable="false"/>
```

And Add this sample code in within Activity

```
    Calendar mcurrentDate=Calendar.getInstance();
        int mHour=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int mMinute=mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        EditText mAddTime=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.add_TimePicker);    
        mAddTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          

                        TimePickerDialog mTimePicker=new TimePickerDialog(AddNewMessage.this, new OnTimeSetListener() {                 
                            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timepicker, int selectedhour, int selectedminute) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

                             mAddTime.setText(selectedhour+":"+selectedminute);

                            }
                        },mHour, mMinute,true);
                        mTimePicker.setTitle("Set Time");
                        mTimePicker.show();   
    }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

For opening Time Pcker Dialog you have to put one Button OR You should use one EditText so you can write on click event of Button or EditText...

You can find example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-time-picker-example/).